# FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments,

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First time asking for help.

Been stuck on this issue for a while.

```js
// Database setup
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { doc, setDoc, addDoc, collection, getFirestore, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
// Your web app's Firebase configuration

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {the data in here}

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

/**
 * Creates new eqipment
 */
export async function opretUdstyr(navn, type, note) {
    try {
        const uuid = generateUUID();
        let nyUdstyr = {
            navn: navn,
            type: type,
            note: note,
            status: "Tilgængelig",
            fra: "",
            til: "",
            UUID: uuid
        };
        const docref = doc(collection(db, 'udstyr'));
        await addDoc(docref, nyUdstyr);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

The error I get is:
FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but udstyr/hRjRFVcgr8Q2nCeHcNbp/8zTbs2qnPOMWW91JTksb has 3.

tried changing the method to the following:

```js
const docref = doc(collection(db, 'udstyr'));
to
const docref = collection(db, 'udstyr');
```

now I get an error I can't see. Honestly have no idea what the errors is.

I have this function above that works like a charm:

```js
export async function getUdstyr() {
    const equipment = collection(db, 'udstyr');
    const snapshot = await getDocs(equipment);
    const result = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return result;
}
```

So its not a case of wrong collection.

EDIT: Since the data arent sensitive here is the entire controller as well as the look of the firestore database.

Firestore database:
[image]

And the controller with the 3 working gets + my create that don't work.

```js
// Database setup
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { doc, setDoc, addDoc, collection, getFirestore, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
// Your web app's Firebase configuration

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAOW2ufaAdHaOvP82u5VwoNVZ9bgkzWh-E",
    authDomain: "booking-system-test-866d0.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "booking-system-test-866d0",
    storageBucket: "booking-system-test-866d0.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "413437808749",
    appId: "1:413437808749:web:610bfaabb471329bbeef64"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

/**
 * Returns snapshot of all equipment
 */
export async function getUdstyr() {
    const equipment = collection(db, 'udstyr');
    const snapshot = await getDocs(equipment);
    const result = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return result;
}

/**
 * Returns snapshot of all bookings
 */
export async function getBookings() {
    const booking = collection(db, 'bookings');
    const snapshot = await getDocs(booking);
    const result = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return result;
}

/**
 * Returns snapshot of all rentings
 */
export async function getUdlaan() {
    const udlaan = collection(db, 'udlaan');
    const snapshot = await getDocs(udlaan);
    const result = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return result;
}

/**
 * Creates new eqipment
 */
export async function opretUdstyr(navn, type, note) {
    try {
        const uuid = generateUUID();
        let nyUdstyr = {
            navn: navn,
            type: type,
            note: note,
            status: "Tilgængelig",
            fra: "",
            til: "",
            UUID: uuid
        };
        /*const docref = collection(db, 'udstyr');
        await addDoc(docref, nyUdstyr);*/

        await addDoc(collection(db, 'udstyr'), nyUdstyr);

        /*const docref = doc(collection(db, 'udstyr'));
        const colref = collection(docref, 'subcollection');
        await addDoc(colref, nyUdstyr);*/

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe one of the params to `opretUdstyr` is null.  Rule that out by adding a literal object that is clearly well-formed, like: `await addDoc(collection(db, 'udstyr'), { testKey: 'testValue' });`

Comment: I have a function on another sheet that checks that beforehand, it won't get into the controller if any of the 3 outside parameters is null. But otherwise a valid problem.

Answer (score 13):

The Firestore data model is:

1. At the top level you have collections.
2. In each collection you (can) have documents.
3. Each each document you can have nested collections again.
4. Etc.

So a path to a document is always going go be `thecollection/thedocid` or `thecollection/thedocid/nestedcollection/anotherdocid`, etc.

In your first code snippet you do:

```
const docref = doc(collection(db, 'udstyr'));
await addDoc(docref, nyUdstyr);
```

The first line here sets up a reference to a document. But the second line then tries to add a document to that document, which isn't possible according to the model I gave.

A document can only exist in a (sub)collection, not directly inside another document. So you can either add it to the top-level collection with:

```
await addDoc(collection(db, 'udstyr'), nyUdstyr);
```

Or if you want, you can add the document to a subcollection with something like:

```
const docref = doc(collection(db, 'udstyr'));
const colref = collection(docref, 'subcollection'));
await addDoc(colref, nyUdstyr);
```

Comment: Tried your subcollection and it did not work sadly.  Your other solution I've tried as well. All of the options come with the same error that my own try second try did. which I wasn't able to catch even with try catch to show the error. If possible would you be interested in a 1 on 1 discord conversation or something similar.

Comment: updated my original post with more information.

Comment: If I'm reading you're update right, you're using the `UUID` in the `ID` field for `GetDocs`. `UUID` is not the doc's ID, the doc's ID is the name you give it. Firebase doesn't recognize "UUID" as the ID. For an example of a `GetDoc` call, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: @Selena , sorry, forgot to @ you, also, I realize that the fact that the document's name is the ID is implied in that link but not outright stated, the [add document docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) make it a bit more explicit... though they keep calling the document's name it's "ID"

Comment: @fabc I am a bit confused with your comment. I've done it exactly as it is done in the documentation await addDoc(collection(db, 'udstyr'), nyUdstyr); this is the one I am using which is the exact same as the link you supplied except they onelined the entire thing where I spread them out in two. When I run the debugger. Everything works until the exact point it runs the addDoc function, and then it fails and never writes to the database. All the data inside "nyUdstyr" comes out as expected. it just never gets written to database. My get methods works so there is a connection to it.

Comment: @Selena Couple of questions: What error do you get? (if you're running a debugger you should see it). Have you tried giving it a name/value, ie use setDoc() in lieu of addDoc(), since it will allow you to specify a name and therefore have more control of the path used?

Comment: @fabc Running the debugging tool the error does not come up. I can't see it at all. As soon it hits the line even if I choose it to freeze there is nothing and it just continues on. I really have no idea what problem it is. Also tried with setDoc() where I specify a name and no change. Writing to my firestore database simply won't happen. Getting from it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @fabc EDIT: I changed nothing in my code, and it just started working. Just did another test pass to show a friend the error, and literally, no change was made. But now it works. I am stupefied.

Comment: @Selena sounds like a great example of IT bug smashing in general. Glad to hear it's solved (even if suddenly and unpredictably), let me know if it happens again, and maybe check for cache (be it dependencies or otherwise) as they tend to cause ephemeral issues.

Comment: @fabc Thank you for trying to help. I wish I could help future people with why my error occurred if theirs happened the same way. But alas I am just happy it works.

Comment: Fair 'nough, have a good one.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the subcollection code.  I've been trying to get this working properly and this code did it.